# Nodemon in docker doesn't work, also --legacy-watch -L are not working

Tags: docker, nodemon

I tried to find solution over a long time - reloading nodemon in docker while updating e.g index.js. I've windows 10.
I've node project with docker:
proj/backend/src/index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello world.')
})
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

proj/backend/package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "start:legacy": "nodemon --legacy-watch -L --watch src src/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

proj/backend/dev.Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN npm install --global nodemon
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm ci
EXPOSE 3001
ENV DEBUG=playground:*
CMD npm run start:legacy
```

proj/docker-compose.dev.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    image: backend-img
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ./dev.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    environment:
      - PORT=3001
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, it's already late. But I will write.

There are misconceptions in your configuration.

1. In command `"start:legacy"`. You should use only one option to run legacy `--legacy-watch` or `-L`, not both. Because these commands are equal. According to nodemon docs: [Via the CLI, use either --legacy-watch or -L for short](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting)
2. Your `Dockerfile` configurations seems fine. But to synchronize your local machine files and directory with docker container you should use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) in `docker-compose`. So, your `docker-compose` file will look something like:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    image: backend-img
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ./dev.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./your_project_dir:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    environment:
      - PORT=3001
```

I believe, if you define `volumes` you will able to make changes locally and container also will see changes

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, the docker container is made for kill itself when the process ends. When using nodemon (and updating the code), the process will be stopped and restarted and the container will `stop`. You could do the npm start not be the main process, but this is not a `good practice`.

Comment: I don't believe that is not a good practice. It's possible if in a course material we can read: https://fullstackopen.com/en/part12/basics_of_orchestration .

Answer (score 0):

index.js

```js
const express = require("express");

const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = "0.0.0.0";

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello Sar Li Ram!");
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

docker-compose.yml

```js
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '3000:8080'
    command: npm run dev
```

Dockerfile

```js
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY  package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "node-with-docker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js "
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

The above solution works for me.